# In a Descartes square are the statements just the negations of each other?

Tags: logic, argumentation, process

There is a decision making method based on wrapping problems into a Descartes square by answering 4 questions.

I've tried to use it for my own decision process but I couldn't figure out what to place into the `"What won't happen if this doesn't happen?"` section.

For me it sounds just like the negation of `"What happens if this happens?"`, thus the same items in a negated form are in there. Is it supposed to help me in my process?

[image: Decart square]

Comment: I can't find the origins of this matrix/square method. I did not read the original meditations tractates by René Descartes, but it does not seem that he would create a such simple thing. Do you know the origins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What happens if this happens ? What happens if person X falls from a 26th floor window on to the pavement ? X dies or is injured.
2. What won't happen if this happens ? What won't happen if person X falls from a 26th floor window on to the pavement ? X won't walk away.
3. What will happen if this doesn't happen ? What will happens if person X doesn't fall from a 26th floor window on to the pavement ? X will attend a meeting in 15 minutes' time.
4. What won't happen if this doesn't happen ? What won't happen if person X doesn't fall from a 26th floor window on to the pavement ? The answer is not necessarily a negation of 1. since X might still die or be injured (in some other way).

I don't know if it's possible to use examples in which the answer to 4. is a negation of the answer to 1. But I can't see that there's any necessary negation between them.